# How to convert entered text into emoji

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ckeditor

I was developing a social networking application using angular technology. I have used CKEditor free version to implement some of the core application features like those below.,

1. Creating a new post component
   [image]
2. Render component
   [image]

I couldn't find the way to convert (user entered) symbols `;) :( :)` to emojis in HTML div tag

If anyone knows please guide me on it

Comment: May be this will help https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/emoji.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, you want to display emoticons on the webpage when users enter their symbol in the textarea.
This can be done using an inbuilt text editor plugin like TinyMCE.
But if you want to try the native way, the simple funda here is:
These emoticon characters are available as Unicode decimal or hexadecimal codepoints when used with UTF-8, a default charset used on webpages.
To get a list of smileys hexadecimal code points, refer to this:
https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf

To display any special character on the webpage, we use '&#x<hexa_code_point>' or '&#<dec_code_point>'.

For eg,

=

&#x1F612 =

&#x1F634 =

so you will need a map between a string entered in your textarea and this code.
For eg,

```
{
 ':|': "1F610"
}
```

and then corresponding to that code point, we can display smiley.

For reference,
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lehmann-ibvncy?file=/index.html

Comment: how to map sting entered `:(`as we do on skype, and it will show the corresponding emoji in the chat box?

Comment: Check this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lehmann-ibvncy?file=/index.html

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding method for Unicode code points using different byte sequences to other Unicode encodings such as UTF-16. Claiming that utf-8 does not support emoji characters is incorrect.  You only need to use HTML escapes in documents that are encoded in a non-Unicode character set, which in 2022 may be unusual. In documents encoded in utf-8 or utf-16 , place Unicode characters  in the source file and declare the encoding with a `meta` tag., If the editor does not support displaying unicode symbols, the obvious options are to change editor, or adjusting its font settings.

Answer (score 1):

The new ckeditor emoji plugin allows you to add emoji. It also auto detectsband filter the relevant emoji based on keywords. e.g.

```
:thumbs_up
```

Add the following line to your congiurations:

```
config.emoji_emojiListUrl
```

And the following link contains demo

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/mentions.html

Comment: I used CKEditor 5 in angular, let me have look if any kind of functionality there or if I think I missed any configuration. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-emojis

Comment: Thanks that you have spent the time on it.